# Use a generated string in the select expr of dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am very new to scala programming, so this might be a basic question

I am planning to create a dataframe dynamically.

This is my end goal :

```
val df2 = df1.select("col1","col2","col3")
```

I have a function which generates these column names as below and saved to a variable like this :

```
scala> val colVar = generateColSelectionString(4)
colVar: String = col1,col2,col3
```

Now,

How do I do something like this:

```
val df2 = df1.select(colVar)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split the string and use `selectExpr`:

```
val df = Seq((1,2,3)).toDF("col1","col2","col3")

val colVar = "col1,col2,col3"

df.selectExpr(colVar.split(","):_*).show
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: That was fast !! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: How do i do the same within groupBy()

Comment: For `groupBy`, you can do something similar like `val cols = colVar.split(","); df.groupBy(cols.head, cols.tail: _*).agg(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Split "colVar" variable, and use "select" with two parameters:

```
val data = List(("v1", "v2", "v3"))
val df = sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")

val colVar = "col1,col2,col3"
val columnList = colVar.split(",")
val result = df.select(columnList.head, columnList.tail: _*)
result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|v1  |v2  |v3  |
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Since I got both the answers at the same time I accepted the first one in the list